# PostgreSQL 9.5: comma separated string using string_agg()

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table with two fields.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE str_agg
(
cola varchar(50),
colb varchar(50)
);
```

Records:

```
insert into str_agg values('Alex','Student');
insert into str_agg values('Mak','Student');
insert into str_agg values('John','Teacher');
insert into str_agg values('Tony','Teacher');
```

I want to display the result in the comma separated format like as shown below:

Expected Result:

```
result
---------------------------------------------------------
Alex(Student),Mak(Student),John(Teacher),Tony(Teacher)
```

**My try**:

```
select string_agg(cola,'('||colb||'),') Result
from str_agg;
```

Getting result:

```
result
---------------------------------------------------------
Alex(Student),Mak(Teacher),John(Teacher),Tony
```

Comment: Why not generate full string first `cola || '(' || colb || ')'` and than pass it to `string_agg` with ',' delimiter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the value `'('||colb||'),'` as the delimiter.

You want:

```
select string_agg(cola||'('||colb||')', ',') Result
from str_agg;
```